# Performance of Multiple RAM Sticks Compared to Single Sticks

Tags: memory, performance, comparison

It's no secret that using two physical drives gives better performance than two partitions on the same physical drive; because there are two devices, they each have their own platters, head, caches, controllers, etc. (eventual system bottlenecks and such aside).

I'm wondering if the same thing is true of RAM. That is, for example (other factors such as speeds, timings, etc. being equal), would installing two 1GB sticks of RAM give better performance than one 2GB stick?

I can't find any useful information on any tests, analyses, or comparisons on this subject. There's plenty of people asking it, but no definitive answers, just speculation.

For the record, I'm not concerned about "one stick allows for future upgrades" or single vs. dual channel (this can be dealt away with by for example doubling everything—in my particular case, I'm trying to determine whether two 1GB sticks is better than four 512MB sticks or vice-versa).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/90109/buying-more-ram has an answer that supports your question. Sure there are two questions in the SU question, but half the of question answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you're not concerned about future upgrades, get the 2 x 1GB sticks. If nothing else, it's fewer points of failure. The speed difference between 4 x 512 and 2 x 1024 is negligible if they're running at the same clock speed and voltage.

It's an academic question anyway, since you won't notice the difference as an end-user. The bottleneck on your system is still the hard drive, whether mechanical or SSD.

---

EDIT:

I've been told that fewer sticks will be quicker, because of the density of the chips on each stick means less travel on the bus than with more sticks. Apparently the timings on 512s are slower than 1GBs too.

Comment: Hmmm, that's interesting because using two physical drives as opposed to two logical drives is definitely *not* academic, the performance advantage is quite distinct. I suppose the difference could be due to the latencies involved (refresh and access times of RAM are so much less than seek and access times of drives).

Comment: I'm sure that there *should* be an advantage for memory-intensive applications that would transfer data between the RAM and CPU (ie, the drive is not involved). Look at the difference in speed between the CPU cache(s) and the RAM speed; the RAM can pull data faster than a single stick can provide, two sticks should be able to push data faster than one stick.

Comment: Only on dual-channel, maybe.

Comment: **> If nothing else, it's fewer points of failure.** By that token, you could also say that if there is a failure, with a one-stick configuration, you lose twice as much as you do with a two-stick configuration.

**> Only on dual-channel, maybe.** Hard-drives aren't dual-channel yet exhibit this behavior. The point is that separate physical devices can ready themselves internally to provide a ready stream of data to the bottleneck (eg bus) whereas a single device could get maxed out.

Comment: I still maintain that the difference is negligible.

Comment: Well then that would be the answer, if there is some sort of confirmation that the speeds of the RAM sticks would be fast enough or the speeds of the bus/CPU are slow enough that the RAM ceases to be the bottleneck. However I can find no information on this, to the contrary, everything I can find indicates that the RAM (specifically the availability of data from the RAM when needed) would be the bottleneck.

Comment: I found this link. I'm not sure if it helps: http://www.overclock.net/intel-memory/29556-ram-cpu-bottleneck.html

Comment: Well it looks like because RAM is much faster than hard-drives, the issue is often moot (at least these days; I’m sure it would have been an issue with older technology). That thread indicates that RAM can actually run as fast as the CPU (which I still find baffling, especially since a CPU’s cache can run at 10x RAM speeds). Either way, it looks like the bus and memory controller play a big role in the potential speeds and it would require a lot of changing and testing the various speeds (FSB, multiplier, RAM timings, etc) to determine if separate sticks would help on a specific, given system.

Comment: Yup, I wasn't quite sure what to make of it, but it's academic anyway. I'm sure a game developer would care more about it than an average end-user, but hey!