# Is dual-channel always faster than a single memory stick setup?

Tags: memory, dual-channel

Is using  2x2gb DDR3 in dual-channel faster than using a single 4gb DDR memory stick on a 4-slot motherboard?

Comment: You might find [Performance of Multiple RAM Sticks Compared to Single Sticks](http://superuser.com/q/234769/) interesting as well, althought it takes a different slant on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

[Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/PARALLEL-PROCESSING,1705-11.html) tested this and the results were that the difference is negligible:

[image: Difference between dual-channel and single-channel]

The main reason for this is probably that even though there are two channels, they still have to interact with the CPU using the same bus which is a pretty huge slowdown for lots of things.